# Should this $\mathbb{C}$ be $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: representation-theory, characters

I'm stuck in the c) part of the next problem

> Let $\rho$ be a representation of the finite group $G$ over $\mathbb{C}$
>
> a) Show that $\delta:g\rightarrow det(g\rho)\ (g\in G)$ is a linear character of $G$.
>
> b) Prove that $G/Ker\ \delta$ is abelian.
>
> c)Assume that $\delta (g)=-1$ for some $g\in G$. Show that $G$ has a normal subgroup of index 2.

So considering $\mathbb{R}$ instead of $\mathbb{C}$, we can define $N$ as the set of elements $g\in G$ with $\delta (g)>0$ and prove the result.

Considering $\mathbb{C}$, I don't know if it's true.

Any advice to prove or disprove it would be a great help.

Comment: I'm actually pretty sure I did this exact problem last semester in rep theory. Let me dig it up real quick and check the verbiage. I *imagine* you do actually want $\mathbb{C}$ because of algebraically closed property. (You probably guessed that already.)

Comment: No, the $\mathbb{C}$ does not need to be an $\mathbb{R}$. Just note that the third condition implies that $ker(\delta)$ is non-trivial, and that there is an element not in that kernel whose square is in it.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft you should post that as an answer.

Comment: Is $G$ a finite group?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown yes, it is.

Comment: @Tobias:  I don't see how c) implies $\delta$ has non-trivial kernel.  If, for example, $G = \mathbb{Z}_{2k}$ maps to the $2k$th roots of 1 on $S^1\subseteq \mathbb{C}$, then $\delta$ has no kernel, but $\delta(k) = -1$.

Comment: @Jason Woops, I meant proper rather than non-trivial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As $G$ is a finite group, the image $\delta(G)$ is a finite subgroup $H$ of the multiplicative group of $\Bbb C$. As $-1\in H$, then $H$ has even order, and a finite abelian group of even order has a (normal) subgroup $K$
of index $2$. Then $\delta^{-1}(K)$ is an index two subgroup of $G$.